# Cannot type "s" into search

Tags: bug, search, mobile-web

As of right now, on the mobile site, I cannot type the character "s" into the search box on the front page.

I'm using the mobile site on an iPhone SE. I am using a browser called Grazing but I can trivially reproduce in Safari, too, both on the main site and here on Meta.

Comment: For what it's worth, finding text with an *s* in it and copy/pasting it into the search box for editing works in the meantime (and of course you can always search via google with `site:stackoverflow.com` as a search term).

Comment: Cross-site dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286345/mobile-search-made-impossible-with-keyboard-shortcuts-enabled

Comment: @tripleee you mean 'ite:tackoverflow.com' ?

Comment: This is caused by the keyboard shortcut JavaScript code. Disabling the shortcuts makes it work correctly again. Pasting works, as does auto-completion.

Comment: For fun and tears: try typing `g`. ;_;

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for the link - I *knew* I had seen this somewhere before, but I clearly didn't search in the right places.

Comment: @Martin You're probably joking but just to be clear, *s* works fine in the Google search box.

Comment: It has started, the revolution of machines. Eventually you'll be able to enter only `1`s and `0`s.

Comment: 01101001 01110100 00100000 01100010 01100101 01100111 01101001 01101110 01110011 00001010

Comment: _it begins_ (for the lazy)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - how is it that that post you linked, from over a year ago, has 17 votes and not a single response explaining what was or wasn't going to be done to address the issue? (apparently nothing was done, but why wasn't the decision to do nothing explained?)

Comment: With only 17 upvotes, it's probably not even displaying on the radar of those who need to know, or at the very least not making it to something they need to do something about.

Comment: The irony is that this post also has 17 upvotes

Comment: "This is caused by the keyboard shortcut JavaScript code. Disabling the shortcuts makes it work correctly again. Pasting works, as does auto-completion" Isn't that an answer, even if not posted ?

Comment: It is a workaround of sorts, but it's not really acceptable. I use the keyboard shortcuts all the time on the desktop version of the site.

Comment: Or simply don't search, which is how I managed to go for this long without noticing, Google's results are basically always orders of magnitude better than the local search. I was simply using search as a means for navigating to a view of questions with a particular tag... and in this case, even that didn't work.

Comment: "_simply don't search_" is the way how the searching engine at SO has been designed anyway.

Comment: Then they should change the text field placeholder from "Search..." to "Don't... just don't".

Comment: `s` and `g` can't be typed, and `h` even brings you to the help page, disrupting your entire searching process. *Edit:* Actually, `g+g` yields `g` and `g+s` yields `s`. But `h` still breaks everything.

Comment: Another option is that simply remove the search bar when the screen size is of mobile.

Comment: Actually, the mobile skin doesn't have a "search bar" per se. There's a looking-glass icon you can access near the top of the questions page, for example. Hiding it entirely seems somewhat excessive. If we really don't want it, hide it from the desktop, too (but then devise some other ways to search tags and favorites and some other vaguely useful things it does).

Comment: Is this still happening? And if so, do you have keyboard shortcuts enabled?

Comment: @NickCraver Seems to be fixed now actually; thanks!